# Como usar a função Máximo Divisor Comum (GCD) em BigINT.js

Tags: javascript

To tentando usar a função `GCD` da biblioteca [BigINT.js](http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js). Mas não sei como, eu tento usar números brutos, mas ela retorna 0

Na descriçao diz que

```js
// bigInt  GCD(x,y)
// return greatest common divisor of bigInts x and y (each with same number of elements).
```

E eu tento usá-la assim:

```js
GCD(1124,2048);
```

Mas ele resulta 0. Como usá-la corretamente?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo código da biblioteca, no mesmo link que você passou, é possível ver que a função `GCD` espera que você passe dois números no formato `bigInt`, e não tipos numéricos do JavaScript.

Para converter tipos numéricos do JavaScript para `bigInt`, existe a função `int2bigInt`.

- é possível ler a seguinte documentação no topo do arquivo:

  > // bigInt  int2bigInt(t,n,m)      //return a bigInt equal to integer t, with at least n bits and m array elements

  traduzindo:

  > // bigInt  int2bigInt(t,n,m)      // **retorna um bigInt igual ao inteiro t, com pelo menos n bits e um array de m elementos**

Depois de obter o MDC, é possível converter o `bigInt` para string e visualizar o seu valor, usando a função `bigInt2str`:

- ainda na documentação no topo do arquivo:

  > // string  bigInt2str(x,base)     //return a string form of bigInt x in a given base, with 2 <= base <= 95

  traduzindo:

  > // string  bigInt2str(x,base)     // **retorna a forma de string a partir de um bigInt x na base dada, sendo que 2 <= base <= 95**

Em suma, para que o seu código funcionar, poderia fazer assim:

```js
var mdc = GCD(int2bigInt(1124,1,1), int2bigInt(2048,1,1));
var str = bigInt2str(mdc, 10);
document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = (str);
```

```html
<script src="http://www.leemon.com/crypto/BigInt.js"></script>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: vc poderia me dizer o que é bigInt?

Comment: É um número inteiro grande, maior que o máximo suportado pelo JavaScript (que é `9007199254740991`, ou 2^53-1, representado no JS numa estrutura equivalente a um `Double`, e insuficiente para as funções de criptografia que você está tentando implementar).

Comment: @bfavaretto um número? To meio perdido..

Comment: Sim, um número! Agora eu é que estou perdido, o que você esperava que fosse?

Comment: é por que nas respostas falaram que tinha que transformar o numero em formato de `bigint`.. Ai quando disse que era um número fiquei meio Oi? @bfavaretto

Comment: Um `bigInt` nessa biblioteca é uma estrutura de dados utilizada para representar um **número inteiro grande**, que o JS não é capaz de representar com seu tipo `Number`. Portanto, um `bigInt` representa um número. @user3163662

Comment: ahhh, ele é tipo uma "camuflagem" de tamanho menor ja que o javascript nao consegue suportar mais que um "double"? @bfavaretto

Comment: Na verdade eles parecem ser arrays, que representam os tais numerões.

Answer (score 2):

A função GCD precisa que seus parâmetros sejam do tipo `bigInt`, e não inteiros. Se você criar bigInts `x` e `y`, você pode então chamar a função corretamente:

```
var BI1 = int2bigInt(1124, 1, 1);
var BI2 = int2bigInt(2048, 1, 1);
var BI3 = GCD(BI1, BI2);
console.log(BI3);
```